# PHP: propagation of constructors or moving constructor to a concrete child

Tags: php, oop

Suppose there is `AbstractClass`:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {

    protected $fooClass;

    public function __construct($fooClass)
    {
        $this->fooClass = $fooClass;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        $this->fooClass->baz();
    }
}
```

`AbstractClass` has a couple of children (1st generation) and these children have their own children (2nd generation). All children are concrete classes.

I want to use the `bar()` method of the `AbstractClass` in a child of the 2nd generation. My first guess is to propagate constructors from 2nd generation to 1st with `parent::__construct($fooClass);`. Not sure if it's good.

If I move the constructor of `AbstractClass` into a child of the 2nd generation, can I call the `bar()` method from that child?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private).

This means there's 2 options:

1. Don't define any constructor for the children (probably not viable in most cases) and assume that only the abstract class constructor exists for all children.
2. Call `parent::__construct` in every child constructor (recommended)

As long as the method `bar()` is not overridden in any child classes it may be called like a class method and will refer to the abstract class method `bar()`.

Comment: from your citation, _Parent constructors are not called implicitly **if** the child class defines a constructor._ i guess i can omit constructors in the children of the 1st generation (if the constructor arguments of the topmost parent and children of the 1st generation are the same).